# What's meaning of NumericLiteralN in F#?

Tags: f#

In the following DSL example (http://fssnip.net/bB), the code is presented:

```
module NumericLiteralN =
    let FromZero() = ""
    let FromOne() = "n"
    let FromInt32 x = String.replicate x "n"

// Calls FromOne():
let x11 = 1N
// val x1 : string = "n"
```

I don't understand this code `let x11 = 1N` at all. I know there is a class  `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.NumericLiteralN` in `FSharp.PowerPack`. Do the codes  overwrite the methods of the `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.NumericLiteralN` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from Tomas' blog  (http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx)

> To define a literal, we need to write a module with a special name.
>   Inside the module, we implement several functions that are used
>   automatically in the F# compiler whenever a literal is used:
>
> ```
> module NumericLiteralZ =  
>   let FromZero () = Z5 0 3:   
>   let FromOne  () = Z5 1  4:   
>   let FromInt32 a = IntegerZ5.Create(a%5) 5:  
>   let FromInt64 a = IntegerZ5.Create(int(a%5L))
> ```
>
> The name of the module consists of the special name NumericLiteral
>   followed by a symbol Z which we’ll use for writing our literals. This
>   means that we’ll be able to write literals such as 0Z, 1Z and 42Z. The
>   module may provide several functions to enable several sizes of
>   literals.

Effectively the name `NumericLiteral"X"` is special and the compiler automatically generates this code to make things work.

In your example, `"n"` is resturned as that is the value of `1` using `FromOne()`.

Your code also has a definition for positive `Int32` values - although it will fail on `-1N`.

Comment: Is the difference between BigNumber and BigInt that BigNum can be float numbers? By the way, how to use the BigNum class in F#? Sorry I am new to F#.